# problem in using SHFILEOPSTRUCT and SHFileOperation

Tags: c++

I am trying to use the [`SHFileOperation()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/shellapi/nf-shellapi-shfileoperationw) function to copy a folder from one directory to another directory.

I wrote the below code using this link: [Copy a Folder](https://www.daniweb.com/programming/software-development/threads/125446/copy-a-folder).

But I get error code 0x7B, and when I searched for information about the error, [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/Debug/system-error-codes--0-499-) says: "The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect."

I wrote the filename and directory name correctly, but I don't know why this code can't copy the `ty` folder from the D drive to another folder called `secondfolder` on the D drive.

Sorry, I searched about this a lot in your website, but I didn't get any answer to my issue.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    system("color 0A")
    SHFILEOPSTRUCT fo;
    memset(&fo, 0, sizeof(fo));
    fo.hwnd = 0;
    fo.wFunc = FO_COPY;
    fo.pFrom = L"D:\\ty\\*\0";
    fo.pTo = L"D:\\secondfolder\\*\0";
    fo.fFlags = FOF_NOCONFIRMMKDIR |
        FOF_NOCONFIRMATION |
        FOF_NOERRORUI |
        FOF_SILENT;
    int n = SHFileOperation(&fo);
    if(n == 0)
    {
        cout << "success" << endl;
    }
    else if (n != 0)
    {
        cout << "faild" << endl;
        cout << hex << n << endl;
    }

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @AlexF read the documentation. Extra null terminators are required on `pTo` and `pFrom`, as they are **double null terminated** lists. `fo.pFrom = L"D:\\ty\\*\0"; fo.pTo = L"D:\\secondfolder\\\0";`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove the `*` from `pTo`:

```
fo.pTo = L"D:\\secondfolder\\\0";
```

Also, you are trying to copy only the contents of `ty`, not copy `ty` itself. If you want that, remove the `*` from `pFrom` as well:

```
fo.pFrom = L"D:\\ty\\\0";
```